# Android Camera safe opening/closing

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I have already read android guidelines and questions on stack about safe opening/closing camera in Android however I haven't found the answer. 
Here is my code snippet for opening camera (inside CameraView class which extends SurfaceView):

```
@Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
                this.camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
            } else {
                this.camera = Camera.open();
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
```

I'm checking the BUILD_SDK because for instance on Nexus7 camera.open() is not working - I have to use camera.open(0)  - but camera.open(int) is not available in SDK 8. And here is my closing camera snippet:

```
@Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        releaseCamera();
    }

    public void releaseCamera(){
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }
```

I'm also using releaseCamera() function when activity connected with my CameraView goes to onPause state. 
This code works fine on most devices (I have checked it on Galaxy GIO, LG 4X HD and Galaxy S2) however I published an app with this code snippet and users still reporting crashes connected to camera, here is the logcat from them:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:423)
at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:384)
at com.artostolab.xray.CameraView.surfaceCreated(CameraView.java:101)
at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:606)
at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:88)
at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:183)
at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:692)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2123)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4879)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And their devices:
LG Optimus G (geehrc4g)
LG Optimus L7 (u0)
IRIS504Q

Do you have any idea why is this happening? Thanks in advance

**UPDATE 21.01.2014**

I used now a function to find back Camera proposed by CommonsWare and it was working fine, however now I go the same error form other users with not so popular devices (Htc EVo 3D, City Life, Huawei U8815). Do you know what may causing this problem? Here is the logcat from them (I updated main question) –

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:300)
at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:253)
at com.artostolab.xray.CameraView.surfaceCreated(CameraView.java:105)
at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:552)
at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:350)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6892)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1884)
at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1524)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1260)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1864)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And my function to find proper camera

```
public int findBackCamera() {
        int cameraId = -1;
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                cameraId = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cameraId;
    }
```

Comment: Why not open a new question? It does not cost extra money, but is much easier to follow and answer. FWIW, your new code does not check that a back camera exists, and working with `cameraId==-1` will crash your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is my code snippet for opening camera

That code is incorrect. `open()` takes the ID of a camera, not `CAMERA_FACING_BACK`.

Comment: doesn't CAMERA_FACING_BACK return integer value?

Comment: yep Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK returns 0 - it's a constant

Comment: @Saqib: So does `Random.nextInt()`. You cannot use a random number with `open()` either. Please iterate over the cameras and find the camera, via its `CameraInfo` that has `facing` set to `CAMERA_FACING_BACK`. See the `findFrontFacingCamera()` method in [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCamera/article.html#tutorial_cameraapi), and modify it to use the back-facing camera rather than front.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks for the explanation, but what if we are sure about the thing, like for the time being it's sure I have two cameras in my device. Plus I have similar issue only occuring on Nexus 3

Comment: @Saqib: "like for the time being it's sure I have two cameras in my device" -- you still do not know whether you want camera ID `0` or `1`. You need to iterate over the available cameras to find the one with the characteristic that you want (in this case, `facing` set to `CAMERA_FACING_BACK`). And there has never been a "Nexus 3" device, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @CommonsWare but Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK is not returning any random value it's a constant value = 0, however I will try to use this tutorial and see what will happen

Comment: @CommonsWare I used now a function to find back Camera and it was working fine, however now I go the same error form other users with not so popular devices (Htc EVo 3D, City Life, Huawei U8815). Do you know what may causing this problem? Here is the logcat form them (I updated main question)

Comment: @user1275995: That error is very generic and could mean anything, sorry.